# Full Calendar Same time events showing one below the other

Tags: fullcalendar

So, I have many events at the same time (usually 6-9 events).
So the week view, which i am using for my page, shows the events the one next to the other causing shrink and not showing the titles properly.

Is there a way to show the events one below the other and force the row height to stretch?
[image]

I tried

```
   /* .fc-timegrid-event-harness {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    display: block;
    left: 0 !important;
    height: 50px;
    } */
```

but of course the table is not resizing according to my needs

Comment: Since the events all occur at the same time, showing them below each other would not be logical at all in a time grid. It would imply that the lower ones start at a later time, when actually that isn't true.

Comment: Have you tried setting https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotEventOverlap to true? (Although that should be the default anyway, unless you've changed it)

Comment: @ADyson , I accept its irrational in a month view but i think it makes sense in a week 
 or a day mode. Tried the overlap but its not working :) Thank you, though

Comment: `i think it makes sense in a week or a day mode`...how? It looks like you have hourly slots. So if, for example, you have 4 events starting at 10am and you show them vertically, with equal size, then to the user it might look like one starts at 10am, one at 10.15, one at 10.30 and one at 10.45. It's potentially very misleading.

Comment: `its not working`...not working how? Please provide a [mre] of the issue. The default setting is for overlaps to happen as per the documentation - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/jOKjPbG . And this is what it looks like with overlap switched off: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/KKejpzZ . It's not a big difference in this case but it does save a little space.